# MSI created by visual studio setup project unable to run exe from installed location

Tags: c#, visual-studio-setup-proje

How i can execute exe after installation from installed location.

Currently it is unable to execute exe from installed location.I have used custom action as well but it is unable to execute exe.

Comment: @Amy my mistake extremely sorry for wrong comment on wrong post.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information.  Execute what? What do your MSI logs show when you try?  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)